# PHP script that keeps running in a web server

Tags: php, webserver

I need a PHP script that checks the info in 2 databases. Then, if there's something new in one of them, insert the new contents into the old one. So basically move info from database 'a' into 'b' and vice-versa so that they both have the same info.

My problem is that I'm not sure how to run a PHP script that keeps running by itself without the need of a browser. It needs to only run on the server.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You shouldn't be using PHP for what you're trying to accomplish. Depending on what type of database you have, most provide functionality to do what you want.

Comment: You can schedule a PHP script to run on the command line with any task scheduler, such as `cron`.  Though most databases have means of performing synchronization themselves and you shouldn't need to reinvent the wheel on this.

Comment: The term you'll be looking for is "database replication", and as others have noted, it's best handled at the database level, not PHP.

Comment: another issue is that the info in the databases is different since it was developed by different teams so all the tables are different and i need to use something like serialize and deserialize in order to get the values, don't know if the database replication can do it, but i'll give it a try, thanks!